# Is RestTemplate thread safe?

Tags: java, spring, rest, thread-safety

Is a Spring `RestTemplate` thread-safe? That is

- Is a `RestTemplate` a Strategy object that multiple connections can safely share. **or**
- Is a `RestTemplate` a connection object (like a data-base connection), which can not be shared while in use, and requires creation afresh, or pooling, for each connection.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242812/how-to-use-resttemplate-efficiently-in-multithreaded-environment

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145558/resttemplate-should-be-static-globally-declared

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747478/is-the-spring-transactiontemplate-and-simplejdbctemplate-thread-safe

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`RestTemplate` [is thread safe](https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate) (emphasis added):

> Conceptually, it is very similar to the `JdbcTemplate`, `JmsTemplate`, and the various other templates found in the Spring Framework and other portfolio projects. This means, for instance, that the **`RestTemplate` is thread-safe once constructed**

---

Objects of the `RestTemplate` class do not change any of their state information to process HTTP: the class is an instance of the Strategy design pattern, rather than being like a connection object. With no state information, there is no possibility of different threads corrupting or racing state information if they share a `RestTemplate` object. This is why it is possible for threads to share these objects.

If you examine [the source code of `RestTemplate`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java) you will see that it does not use `synchronized` methods or `volatile` fields to provide thread-safety after construction of the object. So it is *not* safe to modify a `RestTemplate` object after construction. In particular, it is unsafe to add a message converter.

To provide it with a list of message converters you must do one of the following:

- Use the `RestTemplate(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters)` constructor. As the internal list of `messageConverters` is `final`, this [safely publishes the list of message converters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785455/does-mutation-of-an-non-thread-safe-collection-in-a-constructor-need-to-be-synch).
- Use the `setMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters)` mutator **and** then [safely-publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801993/java-multi-threading-safe-publication?) the changed `RestTemplate` object. Using a Spring bean definition that has a `<property name="messageConverters"><list>...` does this, as the bean [will be safely published by the thread setting up the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510395/does-spring-publish-beans-in-thread-safe-manner) in most practical use cases.
- Use `List.add` on the reference returned by `getMessageConverters()` and then safely publish the changed `RestTemplate` object. However, the documentation for `RestTemplate` does not explicitly state that it returns a reference that can be used to alter the list of message converters. The current implementation does, but possibly the implementation might be changed to return a `Collections.unmodifiableList` or a copy of the list. So it might be better not to change it this way.

Note that the first case is the only means of setting up the message converters when constructing the object, so it **is** correct to say that it "is thread safe once constructed".

The class is part of the Spring Framework, so in almost all practical cases objects of the class will be set up as part of a Spring Application Context, using the first (dependency injection using a constructor) or second (dependency injection using a setter) methods, and so would be guaranteed to be safely published to multiple threads.

Comment: Not only it's thread safe, but its creation seems to be expensive. I recently run on major performance problems on the tomcat because initialization of RestTemplate caused classloader lock contention.

Comment: I don't think its thread safe. It uses messageconverters and you can add messageconverters at runtime from two different threads. And it will throw you concurrentmodificationexception while performing restTemplate.exchange() call, as it iterates through this messageconverters.

Comment: @sakura the "once constructed" condition covers that case.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov I also noticed that performance hit while I was debugging so I googled it and found this.

Comment: I have experienced problem with restemplate. I have spring bean default(singleton) which call .NET REST WS using rest template. With heavy load I have noticed in log mixins of requests and responses from different threads. I am not sure what is the cause, maybe messageConverters, but putting relevant code in synchronized block solved my problem.

I am using spring version 3.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: @gandra404 That *you* have experience problems shows nothing, without further evidence. Perhaps *you* made a mistake, which shows up in a manner that you incorrectly interpret as being the result of a `RestTemplate` not being thread-safe.

Comment: @Raedwald It is true. But when I find time I will post it as a separate question with more info for context. I have tried to put synchronized block and it solved problem. Then I have removed synchronized block and make restTemplate bean to be prototype scope and again I have reproduced same error.

Comment: @Raedwald, Please see this: http://tiemensfamily.com/TimOnCS/2017/08/06/is-spring-resttemplate-thread-safe/ The writer doesn't agree with you.

Comment: So much discussion just confuses the end reader if at all the marked answer is correct or not :( I plan to call same restTemplate object from multiple threads. Can I consider it safe?

Comment: @comiventor If you don't use custom messageConverters then its ok to use one instance of RestTemplate. Otherwise, inject messageConverters via constructor - also thread safe.

Comment: The setInterceptors() method is not thread safe. One thread may be sorting the internal interceptors list, while another clears it. You can't categorically state that an object with mutable state is thread safe. Certain operations are thread safe.

Comment: "Thread safe once constructed" seems to mean "thread safe as long as you don't change its state", which is true in the sense that _any_ object is thread safe as long as its state doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

It is thread safe from the library's point of view. For instance, the getMessageConverters() is public  Which means that if someone gets hold on the list and modifies it outside of the purpose of the library then it will cause issues (and even the setter method, if it's called at any moment after RestTemplate instantiation - and while being used by other threads obviously, boom!). Which probably is what happened to Ross (not enough reputation to reply to the answer, but I'm backing up both the thread-safe and not thread-safe arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, though I might dig the old code out from source control that caused these issues.

I think it would be fair to say that even synchronizing on creation there exist circumstances where another thread can modify the internal collections.  So best be careful.
Looking at the old code, yes it was actually using a message converter.  But only when synchronized on creation.

```
restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
```

After that the only interaction with RestTemplate was with this:

```
return restTemplate.postForObject(url, object, clazz);
```

This is also the line that eventually throws the exception.

There is of course no interaction with the message converter (we have no local reference to it).

Looking at the stacktrace, and the spring source code, the error occurred at this line:

```
for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : getMessageConverters()) {
```

So what do we have?

1. We have concurrent access to the messageConverters
2. If our code didn't do it, then which code did?  I don't have an answer.  My solution at the time was to create a new RestTemplate every time as performance was not a concern in this app.

So in summary, there are circumstances where things may not be thread safe, certainly if you were to play around with message converters directly.  This case though is a strange one, but I thought it would be useful to publish it.

Comment: My guess: after you run `restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());` but do not safely publish the change made to `restTemplate`.

Comment: That is to say, I think **your** call to `restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(...` is not done in a thread safe manner.

Comment: @Raedwald Can you please explain how to safely publish the changes?

Answer (score -4):

Hate to disagree with the accepted answer above (emphasis added), but no it is not Thread safe.  Even after creation.  Internally it is playing around with ArrayLists, I have not dug into the source.  I have seen too many of these:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:677)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:567)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:545)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:253)
```

Comment: The quote and link in the accepted answer is from Spring themselves. So it is safe to assume that RestTemplate is intended to be thread-safe, and failure to be thread safe would be a bug. So until your claim is backed up with a reference to an accepted Spring bug report, I am inclined to think you have made a mistake. For example, by adding message converters after set up.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting approach, if not raised as a bug, it must be incorrect.  This is the world of software my friend, there are all sorts of things that can go wrong, and there are indeed bugs in many accepted systems and libraries.

Comment: Lets have a close look at that stack trace.  getForObject, a standard call via Rest.  Next have a look at the use of the ArrayList and a concurrentModificationException.  Pretty self explanatory really.
In the case of useful discussion I decided to add to this thread what I have seen.  Let people make what they want from it.

Comment: No, not self explanatory as a bug in `RestTemplate`. That the exception is a `ConcurrentModificationException` does not indicate that `RestTemplate` is not thread-safe **once constructed**. It is consistent with your code having altered the `RestTemplate` object, or one of its contained `ArrayList` objects (such as the list of message converters) after construction of the object.

Comment: [There is more to thread safety than use of the `synchonized` keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801993/java-multi-threading-safe-publication).

Comment: Whatever is messing around with those internal collections has nothing to do with our code.  No message converters.
1) Create RestTemplate.  new RestTemplate()
2) use the same template for a while
3) Exception
This is just the way it is I am sorry.  Nothing fancy.

Comment: @Raedwald yes there is more to thread safety than use of the synchronized keyword, such as immutability. If your object has mutable state, and the mutation methods are not thread safe, don't state categorically that the entire object  is thread safe. Some operations are, others are not.