# Can I use the same RestTemplate instance when consuming RESTful services from multiple servers

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate, spring-rest

My RestClient is suppose to consume services from multiple servers, each with different hostname and credentials.

I understand that [`RestTemplate` is thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989500/is-resttemplate-thread-safe?), and creates a different connection for every Task, but how it can be done with different credentials ?
Aren't the credentials provided to the RestTemplate upon creation ?

Comment: are they logically the same services? just with different hosts? or different services?

Comment: Both. Many services, can be divided to groups of the same service with different hosts.

Comment: Why should one do this. It is hard to configure, hard to understand and one has to write some new classes, ..., why do you not use not one RestTemplate per server?

Comment: @Ralph, You're right. I think I'll go for a `RestTemplateFactory` and keep a `RestTemplate` for each server.

Answer (score 3):

You mention credentials, so I'll assume that you use the `RestTemplate` to call services that require authentication. Authentication is usually handled through HTTP request headers (e.g. basic HTTP auth) or URL parameters.

2 possibilities:

- you instantiate a plain `RestTemplate` and handle the authentication manually (by adding the headers or URL parameters when you do a `GET` or `POST`...) => there should be no problem reusing that RestTemplate with multiple service.
- you instantiate the `RestTemplate` with a custom `ClientHttpRequestFactory` or some custom `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` that handle the security => you probably cannot share them because you might mix the different authentications.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that `RestTemplate` for some reason is considered a "heavy" object, so I wanted to create as little as possible, but messing around with manual authentication on each `GET` / `POST` doesn't sound much fun.
I Think I'll keep a `RestTemplate` for each server I use.