# Do we have to create new instance of rest template in each method of integration test cases?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, integration-testing

```html
   
public void Method1() {
restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
}

public void Method2() {
restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
}

public void Method50() {
restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
}

....
```

Cant we create a mock of restTemplate and reuse it in all methods ?

Comment: What exactly is the question? If you instantiate restTemplate inside your method, then no, you cannot put a mock there. If you don't, you can. In most cases, JUnit will run echt method on it's own, anyway, so you will end up creating more restTemplates than you probably think you do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can just create a single instance and re-use it in all the cases. If you use a real RestTemplate in an integration test (say hitting an in-memory service or similar) this will be safe too as [`RestTemplate` is thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989500/is-resttemplate-thread-safe).