# Override restTemplate timeout settings for certain URLs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, connection-pooling, resttemplate

In my spring-boot (2.4.0) app I have set up a connection pool and the timeout for outgoing HTTP requests (30 seconds):

```
@Bean
public RequestConfig requestConfig() {
    return RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(30000)
            .setConnectTimeout(30000)
            .setSocketTimeout(30000)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public CloseableHttpClient httpClient(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager,
                                      RequestConfig requestConfig) {
    return HttpClientBuilder
            .create()
            .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(HttpClient httpClient) {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

I autowire `restTemplate` bean in my Gateway classes and use this `restTemplate.exchange(...)` to perform HTTP requests. The timeout itself works fine and is applied to all outgoing requests.

But for certain URLs I need to set the timeout to 5 seconds.

Is there a way to override generic timeout settings for certain URLs?

Answer (score 0):

I had this very this problem recently and had two versions of `RestTemplate`, one for **"short timeout"** and one for **"long timeout"**. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48362053/2039546)

> RestTemplate was really designed to be built with pre-configured timeouts and for those timeouts to stay untouched after initialization. If you use Apache HttpClient then yes you can set a RequestConfig per request and that is the proper design in my opinion.