# Configure different timeouts for end points in Rest Template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I  have a spring boot client application that uses RestTemplate to talk to a few  end points. Right now the resttemplate has the same connect timeout for each end point.

There is a new requirement to configure different timeouts based on the end point. I am using RestTemplateBuilder to configure the Rest Template during application start up.
After reading through other posts I figured there are  couple of ways to achieve this.

First option is to configure a rest template for each end point(want to stay away from this as there could be lot  of end points in future) and the second option is to have the ability  to set connect timeouts for every request .

I specifically want to check  if there is a way to set timeouts per request  using the same rest template.

Comment: almost same to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361794/resttemplate-set-timeout-per-request/48362053#48362053

Comment: May I ask, what's wrong with creating RestTemplate instances as needed?

Comment: @Deadpool  yes  can  maintain a  resttemplate factory .Wanted to see if there is a way to achieve this with a single rest template

Comment: I did reopened your question from duplicate flag, but not sure about best answer other than in the linked @rookie

Comment: edited the question so its  more specific now