# Is RestTemplate thread-safe

Tags: spring-boot, concurrency, resttemplate

I'm constructing a `RestTemplate` object once within a `@PostConstruct` method and using that instance to make all HTTP calls from my app. For example:

```java
@Service
public class MicroserviceIntercomm {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private @Autowired RequestBean requestBean; //RequestScope

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IllegalArgumentException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSecretProvidedException, NoAlgorithmSetException, GenerateTokenException, InvalidEndpointException {
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpReq = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        clientHttpReq.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
        clientHttpReq.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpReq);  
    }

    public void apiCallFoo() {
        headers.set(headerName, requestBean.getJwtToken());
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    }

    public void apiCallBar() {
        headers.set(headerName, requestBean.getJwtToken());
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    }
}
```

From the documentation it isn't clear whether or not using `RestTemplate` this way is thread-safe.

According to [this blog article](https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate) it is:

> This means, for instance, that the RestTemplate is thread-safe once constructed, and that you can use callbacks to customize its operations.

However, when viewing the Javadocs for the [`exchange()` method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-org.springframework.http.RequestEntity-java.lang.Class-), it isn't explicitly listed that the method is thread-safe.

Should we make changes to this code to make it thread-safe, or does it work as intended?

We're using Spring boot 1.5.10.RELEASE.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989500/is-resttemplate-thread-safe http://tiemensfamily.com/TimOnCS/2017/08/06/is-spring-resttemplate-thread-safe/

Comment: How about use RestTemplate the recommended way, which is to expose it as a `@Bean` ? She can't argue with you using RestTemplate the [documented way](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)...

Comment: `RestTemplate` is thread safe by design. It doesn't hold state at the class level. Your own code however isn't thread safe, you have a globally exposed `headers` object, which you modify inside the methods. Leading to multiple threads using each others token...