# How to work correctly with ThreadPoolExecutor in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency

I have a `Spring Boot Application`.

My application sends requests to another applications using `restTemplate`.

I need to send a request to one hundred different applications(on different servers). I use:

```
publi class Service {
    private RestClient restClient;
    private List<String> urls;
    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public Service(RestClient restClient, List<String> urls, ThreadPoolExecutor executor){
       this.restClient = restClient;
       this.urls = urls;
       this.executor = executor;
    }

    public void sendPost(Entity entity){
         for (String url: urls){
             executor.execute(() -> restClient.create(url, entity);
         }
    }

}
```

I am trying to use `ThreadPoolExecutor(fixedSizeThreadPool)` but I have some questions.

**1**.I read up that `threadPoolExecutor` is thread-safe. Does It means that I can invoke `execute()` at the same time from different threads and It will work properly?
**2**. If there are no idle threads in `threadPoolExecutor` It will slow down the application and I should to choose rational pool size, right?
**3**. For example, I need to write executed urls in `ArrayList`:

```
public void sendPost(Entity entity){
         List<String> executedUrls = new ArrayList<>();  
         for (String url: urls){
             executor.execute(() -> restClient.create(url, entity, executedUrls);
         }
}
```

`RestClient` sends a request and if It is successfully executed It will be added in `ArrayList`.

I expect that `ArrayList` will have list of successfully executed urls If I have an exception in any thread from `threadPool`.
 Will It work as I expect or I can have something like *lost update*?

Comment: Yes, you should use a rational upper bound for thread count. You should be fine with more than cpu cores because it's i/o work. No, it won't work as you expect in all cases because the executor might be thread safe but an `ArrayList` isn't, use a concurrent list.

Comment: What is that `RestClient`? `ThreadPoolExecutor` is "designed" for threads, but everything (what happens) inside `create(...)` *should consider thread-safety* /is not automatically thread safe! ... and "concurrency over IO": ...is possible, but not desirable! ..you should (re-)consider your architecture and "deployment structure". 1. yes 2. yea...an important setting (see "concurrency over IO") 3. `ArrayList` is *not thread safe* (, which means: "you cannot rely on its content/size/..." in concurrency).

Comment: @xerx593 RestClient is responsible for creation HttpHeaders and then HttpEntity for sending requests with restTemplate.

Comment: @xerx593 My application has replicas. All replicas must have identical data. Any application must execute the request. I thought that I could use ThreadPoolExecutor to send the request to replicas and after execute It locally. It looks better than sending the request in foreach, am I not right?

Comment: ..so a "custom class"!?  yes, please see comments on `create(..)`: you *should* synchronize! (...not the complete method, that would be analogous to sequential processing (with random order), only, and this is the art:)... the "sensible parts": where I would merely include things like: `list.contains()` or `list.add()` ...[`restTemplate` is "considered thread safe" here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22989500/592355), but ["google" contradicts](http://tiemensfamily.com/TimOnCS/2017/08/06/is-spring-resttemplate-thread-safe/)..

Comment: ..your "deployment structure" in mind: 1. "data base" sounds like a good place for "`executedUrls`"!(?) ...and it sounds like you also *can better* parallelize: share the job (additionally) over the replicas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use an `ExecutorService`.
For example, create a new `ExecutorService` (a cached `ThreadPoolExecutor` might be the better one)

```
private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

Create a custom `Runnable` implementation

```
static class RestRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final String url;
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final Collection<? super String> executedUrls;

    RestRunnable(
            final String url,
            final RestTemplate restTemplate,
            final Collection<? super String> executedUrls) {
        this.url = url;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.executedUrls = executedUrls;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final ResponseEntity<?> response = restTemplate.exchange(...);

        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            executedUrls.add(url);
        }
    }
}
```

And for each `URL`, submit a new task to the `ExecutorService`

```
final Collection<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
final Collection<String> executedUrls = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

...

for (final String url : urls) {
    // The RestTemplate instance is retrieved via Spring Bean, or created manually 
    executorService.submit(new RestRunnable(url, restTemplate, executedUrls));
}
```

`RestRunnable` will insert the `URL` in the `executedUrls` thread-safe `CopyOnWriteArrayList` if it was invoked successfully.

---

Remember the `ExecutorService` **must** be shutted down when not needed anymore.

Comment: It can be needed to execute different request methods, not only post. Following this example I should create different RestRunnable for different methods. Perhaps it's not the best choice. And in fact It is not necessary to check status code because if I don't have an exception it's already successful execution.

Comment: @Donatello no, you should check the status, always. **It is** ok to have multiple implementations of Runnable for each HTTP call type. Alternatively you can pass another parameter to parameterize the type of call.

Comment: Is it use of CopyOnWriteArrayList faster than synchronized block on arrayList.add() operation? CopyOnWriteArrayList creates a new array after every mulative operation

Comment: @Donatello CopyOnWriteArrayList will always be better then manually synchronizing. Manual sychronization is also error prone if you don't know what you're doing. Avoid it as much as you can

Comment: @Donatello you can also pass a Supplier<T> to RestRunnable. The Supplier can be created using a *lambda expression*, and you can directly build your call logic  there.

Comment: It's necessary to create new RestRunnable() every time. I can use lamba instead: executorService.submit(() -> {code is here}). What is the advantage of creation RestRunnable then?

Comment: @Donatello A lambda should be two/three lines maximum. I prefer extracting it to a specific private static class. With a lambda, an anonymous class would be created anyway, with performance penalties too.

Comment: @Donatello obviously mine was a generic example. You can tweak that class as much as you want for your specific needs, but the logic remains.