# RestTemplate Multitheading issue

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am facing issue with restTemplate, in a multithreaded environment. I am calling a Rest api with url http://localhost:8080/search, its a post request and I pass a object which have search parameters. I use this to search user,dept etc. This returns a response search object which has such structure, First one is for user and second is for dept

```
{"totalCount":2,"startIndex":0,"endIndex":1,"resultList":[{"username":"a", userid:"1}, {"username":"b", userid:"2"}, {"username":"c", userid:"3"} ]}
{"totalCount":2,"startIndex":0,"endIndex":1,"resultList":[{"deptname":"a", deptid:"1"}, {"deptid":"b", deptid:"2"} ]}
```

Sometimes if api is slow the response return is overridden, like for dept and user the same response will be returned like

```
{{"totalCount":2,"startIndex":0,"endIndex":1,"resultList":[{"username":"a", userid:"1}, {"username":"b", userid:"2"}, {"username":"c", userid:"3"} ]}
```

I am autowiring a single instance of restTemplate. Also I have tried creating a new instance of restTemplate for each request but that didnt helped.

I am autowiring a single instance of restTemplate. Also I have tried creating a new instance of restTemplate for each request but that didnt helped.

------------Update-------------

Controller Code is something like:

```
            @RequestMapping("search")
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> search(String type,
        String start, Integer count) {

    Map<String, Object> responseJson = new HashMap<>();

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setCount(count);
    criteria.setStartCount(start);
    criteria.setType(type);

    Result<?> result;
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/search";
    HttpEntity<Object> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>();
    ResponseEntity<? extends Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Result.class);

    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        responseJson = (Result<?>) response.getBody();
    }

    return responseJson;
}
```

I have also checked the API code and seen that they are sending correct response when I received the overridden response. So looks like the request parameters are passing correctly and the response what API is sending is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you have problem with your controller using shared variable. Please post your controller code so that we can help you.

Comment: Added controller code in my question.

Comment: Are you using global variables instead of local variables in you Controller? If so, that's causing it. Show us the whole code of your controller class (omit non relevant code).

Comment: I dont think I am using any global variables, the parameter that I am getting in the request are then send to API. Updated code.

Comment: At this point, I am thinking the problem is in the server side.

Comment: Thanks Edward, I tried the same request from postman and everytime response is same.

Comment: I realized that there was a global variable in my Result object which was causing this. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me well, RestTemplate's exchange method is not thread-safe. That is why Spring does not create RestTemplate as a bean. ([RestTemplate thread-safety question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989500/is-resttemplate-thread-safe))

Autowire and use RestTemplateBuilder to get a new RestTemplate. It will solve your problem.

```
@Autowired RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder; 

@RequestMapping("search")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> search(String type,
        String start, Integer count) {

    Map<String, Object> responseJson = new HashMap<>();

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setCount(count);
    criteria.setStartCount(start);
    criteria.setType(type);

    Result<?> result;
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/search";
    HttpEntity<Object> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build(); // <-- here here
    ResponseEntity<? extends Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Result.class);

    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        responseJson = (Result<?>) response.getBody();
    }

    return responseJson;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Edward, RestTemplateBuilder is part of spring boot and I am not using it.

Comment: If that's the case, given the RestTemplate's exchange method is not thread-safe, why don't you use a factory as a bean (autowire this factory) and generate the RestTemplate for you to use ?

Comment: I tried creating a new instance of RestTemplate for each request but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`RestTemplate` is not a thread-safe class, so the use of it in a multithreaded environment would get into a weird situation. To avoid that, you create an instance on each request by simply using the `new` operator:

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

Comment: Have checked API response correctly through another source such as postman or curl