Junit mock is not working for mockito call
In this test case
mockStatic.when(() -> selfServiceDaoHelper.auditApiRequestData(any(MapSqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(1);
when(restTemplate.exchange(any(), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(MemberDataValidationResponse.class)))
.thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(mockResponse));
these calls are not working and hitting the method. Can anyone please help me on this.
@Test
    public void testValidateMemberData_Success() throws Exception {
        MemberValidationRequest memberRequest = new MemberValidationRequest();
        memberRequest.setCorelationIdentifier("123");

        MemberDataValidationResponse mockResponse = new MemberDataValidationResponse();
        mockResponse.setStatus("200");

        HttpHeaders headers = SelfServiceValidation.populateTokenHeaders();
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(new JSONObject(memberRequest).toString(), headers);
        
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = Mockito.mock(ApplicationContext.class);

        SelfServiceDaoImpl selfServiceDao = Mockito.mock(SelfServiceDaoImpl.class);
        SelfServiceDaoHelper selfServiceDaoHelperTest = new SelfServiceDaoHelper();
        selfServiceDaoHelperTest.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        when(applicationContext.getBean(SelfServiceDaoImpl.class)).thenReturn(selfServiceDao);
        
        Mockito.when(postgresJdbcTemplateTest.update(any(), any(MapSqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(1);

        when(restTemplate.exchange(any(), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(MemberDataValidationResponse.class)))
                .thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(mockResponse));
        
        
         try (MockedStatic<SelfServiceDaoHelper> mockStatic = mockStatic(SelfServiceDaoHelper.class)) {
             // this down mock is not working as expected
             mockStatic.when(() -> selfServiceDaoHelper.auditApiRequestData(any(MapSqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(1);        
             mockStatic.when(()->applicationContext.getBean(SelfServiceDaoImpl.class)).thenReturn(selfServiceDao);
                     
         assertEquals(1, SelfServiceDaoHelper.auditApiRequestData(new MapSqlParameterSource()));
         };
        

        MemberDataValidationResponse result = SelfServiceValidation.validateMemberData(memberRequest);

        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals("200", result.getStatus());
    } 

the methods calling are as below :
public static MemberDataValidationResponse validateMemberData(MemberValidationRequest memberValidationRequest)
            throws Exception {
        MemberDataValidationResponse memberValidateResponse = new MemberDataValidationResponse();
        try {
            if (isSelfServicePortalServerAvailable(selfServicePortalURL)) {
                String corelationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                String spanId = corelationId + SelfServicePortalConstants.MEMBER_VALIDATION_CODE;
                HttpHeaders headers = populateTokenHeaders();
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                String validateMemberAPI = selfServicePortalURL + Endpoints.MEMBER_VALIDATION;
                log.info("Self Service Portal API URL :{}", validateMemberAPI);
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(memberValidationRequest);
                String requestBody = jsonObj.toString();
                HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);
                processRequestAudit(memberValidationRequest, corelationId, spanId, ipAddress.toString(),
                        "Member Validation", "Claim Submission");
                UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(validateMemberAPI);
                ResponseEntity<MemberDataValidationResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                        builder.buildAndExpand().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST, request, MemberDataValidationResponse.class);
                memberValidateResponse = (MemberDataValidationResponse) response.getBody();
                processResponseAudit(memberValidateResponse, "", spanId, corelationId);
            } else {
                log.info(SELF_SERVICE_PORTAL_UNAVAILABLE_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            throw new RuntimeException(cause);
        }
        return memberValidateResponse;
    }

The is the second method call
public static String processRequestAudit(Object inquireClaimFilterRequest, String corelationId, String spanId,
                String ipAddress, String serviceType, String responseStatus)
                throws UnknownHostException, JsonProcessingException {
            String auditStatus = "";
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String requestJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(inquireClaimFilterRequest);
            LocalDateTime myDateObj = LocalDateTime.now();
            DateTimeFormatter dateStampObj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            String dateStamp = myDateObj.format(dateStampObj);
            LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStamp, dateStampObj);
            MapSqlParameterSource auditParams = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            auditParams.addValue(SRVC_TYPE_NAME, serviceType);
            auditParams.addValue(CORLTN_ID, corelationId);
            auditParams.addValue(RQST_IP_ADRS, ipAddress);
            auditParams.addValue(RQST_TIMESTAMP, Timestamp.valueOf(myDateObj));
            auditParams.addValue(RQST_BODY, requestJson, java.sql.Types.OTHER);
            auditParams.addValue(RSPNS_TIMESTAMP, null);
            auditParams.addValue(RSPNS_BODY, null, java.sql.Types.OTHER);
            auditParams.addValue(SRVC_RSPNS_STATUS, responseStatus);
            auditParams.addValue(OPRTNL_FLAG, OPRTNL_FLAG_A_VAL);
            auditParams.addValue(CREATED_BY, "1");
            auditParams.addValue(CREATED_DATE, localDateTime, java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP);
            auditParams.addValue(MODIFIED_BY, "1");
            auditParams.addValue(MODIFIED_DATE, localDateTime, java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP);
            auditParams.addValue(SPAN_ID, spanId);
            int auditResponse = SelfServiceDaoHelper.auditApiRequestData(auditParams);
            if (auditResponse == 1) {
                auditStatus = "Audit Data Inserted Successfully";
            } else if (auditResponse == 0) {
                auditStatus = "Audit Data Insertion Failed";
            }
            return auditStatus;
        

}

You are using try-with-resource block for your MockStatic:
try (MockedStatic<SelfServiceDaoHelper> mockStatic = mockStatic(SelfServiceDaoHelper.class)) {
  // this down mock is not working as expected
  mockStatic.when(() -> selfServiceDaoHelper.auditApiRequestData(any(MapSqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(1);        
  mockStatic.when(()->applicationContext.getBean(SelfServiceDaoImpl.class)).thenReturn(selfServiceDao);
                     
  assertEquals(1, SelfServiceDaoHelper.auditApiRequestData(new MapSqlParameterSource()));
};

Static stubs are active only in scope of this block.
They are not active after you exit it.
You need to call your method under test in scope of this block.
For restTemplate
You are creating a new RestTemplate in method under test RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); thus stubbing in test does not have any effect. You need to pass RestTemplate to class under test - ideally in constructor.

this is working but i have one more concern . Rest Template call mock is also not working .. could you please give any direction on it.

You are creating a new RestTemplate in method under test RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); thus stubbing in test does not have any effect. You need to pass RestTemplate to class under test - ideally in constructor. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989500/is-resttemplate-thread-safe

Is there any other way we can mock instead of passing it in constructor. I don't want to modify the code.

In integration test, spinning up wiremock is a great choice. In unit test injecting your dependencies is the right choice. You can resort to MockedConstruction, but IMHO it is a code smell. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-mockito-mockedconstruction
